# CTCellularPlanProvisioning().supportsCellularPlan() takes too long

Tags: ios, swift

Calling  `CTCellularPlanProvisioning().supportsCellularPlan()` which returns boolean if the device supports esim takes up to 10 seconds to complete which freezes the app. This method seems to be trivial to execute which leads to question why is it taking so long? And how to avoid the app freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the problem execute the method on a different thread:

```
func checkEsim(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
  DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let value = CTCellularPlanProvisioning().supportsCellularPlan()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      completion(value)
    }
  }
}
```